# In vim, how to paste without copy selected content when select some content before

Tags: vim, copy, paste

I usually want to replace some content in vim. After copy, I select the content to be replaced, then paste content I copied. But then the content to be replaced will be copied to clipboard, and I can't replace next place.
I hope content in clipboard don't change when I paste on some selected place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can vim keep the content of register when pasting over selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723700/how-can-vim-keep-the-content-of-register-when-pasting-over-selected-text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to paste over without overwriting register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290465/how-to-paste-over-without-overwriting-register)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer: `"0p`** (instead of `p`)

This question sort of has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468699/how-to-keep-my-buffer-when-copy-cut-then-paste-a-word-with-vim/13468783#13468783), but I will add more details.

The `:registers`, command will show you what the registers are currently storing.
(use `:help registers` for more information)

Explanation:

Using the double quote (`"`) before a `yank` or `put` command tells vim you want to use a specific register.  The command `"xp` (where `x` is a number (0-9), or a letter (a-z)) says you want to `put` the data that was stored in register x.
In your case, you want to retrieve from register 0, because that was what you most recently `yank`ed.  (Every `yank` you do automatically fills register 0 with the text, as well as the unnamed register that is used by default with each `yank` and `put`)

You could also choose a named register to store your data in.  I will choose letter 'h', for example.
To `yank`: `"hy`.  To `put`: `"hp`.

Now if you use the `:registers` (or `:reg`) command, you will see that you have text stored in your `"h` register.

([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497958/how-do-i-use-vim-registers) is a question that explains registers very well)

Answer (score -1):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.